# Can I redefine a macro with another #define directive?

Tags: c, macros, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I want to redefine the value of a macro constant with another value. Now I know the technique of using `#undef` and thereafter re-`#define` the macro itself, like:

```
#define LEN_OSG 59
....
#undef LEN_OSG
#define LEN_OSG 70
```

I´d attempt to abbreviate this and discovered that it is *possible* to redefine the macro constant by just another `#define` directive:

```
#define LEN_OSG 59
....
#define LEN_OSG 70
```

[Example program](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaIAEylV6ADJ5amAHJ6ARpmJcAzKQAOqaYSW1NO/Ubunt50Fla2ug5OnK6y8op0DATMxAR%2BegbGcZgKPkkpBGE29o4uMsmp6QFZFYWWxZGlMQCUMqjaxMgcAOQApIbOlsg6WADUvc7q0gT4qAB0CBPYvQAMAIKrGwNYVPWjZtjWYgDyDADiowCsAJybm5YEo7rMlhDNdwDsAEJ366P/ozcxAeVAg/UMByOpwueGk40Ml3Qc16l3UtHBpEhJ3O72cP3WmwB8OcOz2WOhow%2BK0JAJp/yBILBhghh2xMLh/URyOZmNZ0Nx%2BI2HwAIt1WqwQN1Lt1SAZuisZahJepRtJ2p1MMTODKCJKFc1WgBrEDOZxzU0Wy1WgBsQkl3BlcoVpCV3Rl0hAK1IuvlYtIcFgMEQKFQujceHYZAoEDQYYjpWQwGuxl2rAIjg9EDsepldksKQAnpLtaRY7pVARjrRWEXfaQsM9ROwc/W8MQcooAG6YD11zAADxy2nTLYechbrDwdmIhc0WGLOuBugXrRo9CYbA4PH4gmEohAEjEUkndg9kFaqDcCVovYAtAB1Nisd1yDs%2BFRqKoGTgmNRFCJRIIHheNeX5AcE17/iU0QyK%2BuSJLUYE/tk8G0PkqRQY0MHTAUSHlAUmGAZwrRqh0XRcOKkrSrKLauv2AAc1q3ta3CjMAyDIKM1xzIYowQLghAkFqpCjJocaRlqzSiTqOYGqQxqXF6ErdA6pDLopNF1q67qet6sn%2BkGEBIO0BBuMO5CULG4aRoImD4EQMFrowLDNtuADuM5uCudpSo6tGSv0zicKMbmEAgowMUxLFsRxXE8TJvpyQgmDMFgThvPJXArEp9oyupXpOoqko6V6Pr6kaJpmla1UWraynOH5WnFXpiUGfAAbBlZ8ZRpZobWQmwwiEm2WkKm6bEJm2Z1nmtCFgupahuW9BVjWLYNkNzZ1vg7a5N2vbOgOQ4jnWY7Kc6J4zsQBZzj0JYEEu3lORurm8AIxh7uIkhCFOZ4ZZe169i%2B8TvhAph4aYhFNEEIE%2BHhwEhLQkPYXB17oWkWgZIIKGo7USNY4hGMBMhuP1ABTQkeq5HET51GFS6kqRcxrGDaIcUrHMKx8QJDnCaJfXdcShhSeoCXlZlprmjV1U%2Bap%2BWac62kyLpZV%2Bh1RkgCZZkEBZMb8zZxh2YJjl0M5m5cLwHnMF53TapRvny0VfQDLxoUEOFjPRSzwBsxzotiq0yWpaUGXKbLIAaXTiseqVskVRLUvS/VjUK81KtycphjJ47ftyd2E3vtwQA%3D%3D):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN_OSG 59

int main()
{

    printf("LEN_OSG is %d.\n",LEN_OSG);

    #define LEN_OSG 70

    printf("LEN_OSG is %d.",LEN_OSG);
}
```

---

Of course, Both gcc and clang give me the warnings:

> warning: "LEN_OSG" redefined.  (gcc)

and

> warning: 'LEN_OSG' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined] (clang)

but they do compile it (without the `-Werror` option of course) and give both the correct result:

```
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 0
LEN_OSG is 59.
LEN_OSG is 70.
```

My questions:

- Can I redefine a macro with another #define directive by ignoring this specific warning?
- Does this in any kind involve undefined behavior or cause a potential harm to the program?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You might take a closer look at `#undef`

Comment: @Gerhardh Where should I look at by `#undef`in particular? I do not get the clue.

Comment: You have a warning because a macro is already defined. Now you have a preprocessor directive that makes a macro become not defined any more. Seems to be a perfect match for me.

Comment: Instead of trying to screw around with preprocessor directives, write a new question explaining the larger goal you are trying to achieve and asking how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefining a macro (when the redefintion is not the same) is a *constraint violation*.  The constraint is spelled out in sectino 6.10.3p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **An  identifier  currently  defined  as  an  object-like macro  shall 
>   not  be  redefined  by  another `#define` preprocessing  directive  unless
>   the  second  definition  is  an  object-like  macro definition  and 
>   the  two  replacement  lists  are  identical.**   Likewise,  an 
>   identifier  currently defined   as   a   function-like   macro   shall 
>   not   be   redefined   by   another `#define` preprocessing  directive 
>   unless  the  second  definition  is  a  function-like  macro 
>   definition that  has  the  same  number  and  spelling  of  parameters,
>   and  the  two replacement  lists  are identical.

And section 4p2 states the following about constraint violations:

> **If  a  ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall  not’’ requirement  that  appears  outside
>   of  a  constraint  or  runtime-constraint  is  violated,  the 
>   behavior  is  undefined.**   Undefined  behavior  is  otherwise indicated
>   in  this  International  Standard  by  the  words  ‘‘undefined 
>   behavior’’  or  by  the omission of any explicit definition of
>   behavior.  There is no difference in emphasis among these three; they
>   all describe ‘‘behavior that is undefined’’.

So redefining a macro invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  You **must** use `#undef` if you want to redefine the macro.

Answer (score 1):

You should really get used to using `#undef` before re-defining a macro! Most compilers will generate a warning; however, according to the [C99 Standard](http://www.dii.uchile.cl/~daespino/files/Iso_C_1999_definition.pdf) (and also the [C18 Standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) - the paragraphs are the same in both):

> **6.10.3 Macro replacement**
>  ...
>   2 An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro shall not be redefined by another #define preprocessing directive unless the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical. Likewise, an identifier currently defined as a function-like macro shall not be redefined by another #define preprocessing directive unless the second definition is a function-like macro definition that has the same number and spelling of parameters, and the two replacement lists are identical.

The 'replacement lists' for the `LEN_OSG` (object-like) macro in your example are `59` and then `70` - which are *not* identical.